# Colunas repetidas estilo árvore

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

estou com uma dificuldade em construir um relatorio no jasper, que deveria ter a seguinte impressão, segue ex:

```
Código SubCodigo Código Final
01        001       001
                    002
          003       001
                    002
                    003
          006       001
```

O problema que já rodei, rodei, pesquisei e pesquisei e todos que verifiquei nenhum se assemelha a este tipo de relatório.

Caso alguma alma bondosa passou por tal situação, por favor, me mostre o caminho das pedras.

Comment: Não entendi muito bem o cenário, mas parece que você precisa criar um grupo no seu relatório, e definir uma Variável que seja do tipo String concatenando os pais até que o grupo seja alterado. A dificuldade parece que vai ser identificar qual será o seu campo para agrupamento, será necessário - talvez - criar uma coluna na consulta que represente o agrupamento que você precisa.